# Old shapeshift account with secret key. How do I extract my ETH address?

Tags: wallets, private-key, recovery, shapeshift

My secret key looks like this, but its all numbers. No letters or words at all. The format looks like this:

500000 100000 300000 600000 400000 411111 900000 400000 611111 811111

I have some FOX tokens stored there and would like to retrieve them. Which wallets will let me recover my ETH addresses using the example key above?

Comment: Did you try concatenating all the digits? It seems to be less than 2**256-1, so it might be an ECDSA private key.

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: In python I'd use something like `"0x{:x}".format(500000100000300000...)`. Perhaps you can use a calculator that supports large numbers, and just type the digits.